# Why am I getting NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler in code that doesn't modify source array/set?

Tags: objective-c, healthkit

In my crash logs for my latest app version, I got an `NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler` followed by a crash referencing `HKAnchoredObjectQuery initWithType` for my code, but I am not intentionally mutating the NSMutableSet `sources` over which I am fast enumerating.

Here's my code:

```
    for(HKSource* source in sources){
        NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSources:[NSSet setWithObject:source]];
        HKAnchoredObjectQuery *newQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:quantityType predicate:predicate anchor:anchor limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit completionHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSUInteger newAnchor, NSError *error) {
            completion(results);
        }];

        [healthStore executeQuery:newQuery];
    }
```

Any suggestions as to why I am triggering `NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler`? I am not explicitly touching `sources` nor have I made a copy of it...is there a way `HealthKit` could be modifying the `source`? Even if it were, I would think that modifying `source` shouldn't trigger this as I am not directly touching `sources`. Any trouble-shooting advice or error-spotting would be much appreciated.

Here's the exact text from the crash log:

```
Latest Exception Backtrace:
1. libobjc.A.dylib     objc_exception_throw
2. CoreFoundation      _NSFastEumerationMutationHandler
3. App name             0x1000d8000
4. App name             0x1000d8000
5. App name             0x1000d8000
6. HealthKit           _79-[HKAnchoredObjectQuery initWithType:predicate:anchor:limit:completionHandler:]_block_invoke     <---this must be referring to my code above, as it's the only call to initWithType inside a fast enumeration
7. HealthKit           _81-[HKAnchoredObjectQuery deliverSampleObjects:deletedObjects:withAnchor:forQuery:]_block_invoke_2     <-- this is an internal HealthKit call. deliverSampleObjects is not a publicly listed method of the interface.
```

I have not had a crash in the sim or on my phone, so this is the only info I have to go on.

Comment: Update your question with the complete and exact error message.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for taking a look. I have updated my question to include the text from the crash logs.

Comment: You left out the actual error message. And fully symbolicate that crash log so you can point out the exact code being referenced in that stack trace.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't understand your suggestion. The text is all I have from the crash logs. I don't have anything more. And I don't know what fully symbolicate the crash log means, but I do not have direct access to the crash log, so in any case this is the best I can do.

Comment: Lines 3, 4, and 5 of the stack trace are from your app. But those lines don't show methods names, filenames, or line numbers. Symbolicating the crash log with give you that info. Then you can see the exact lines of your code involved in the crash. And for the 3rd time now, update your question with the actual error message shown in the crash report.

Comment: @rmaddy As I said all I have is what's above. It was cut and pasted from the person who actually has access to the crash logs. I don't get this info directly.

Comment: You should get the actual crash log from the user if you can. But as gnasher729 mentions, most likely your `completion(results)` call is modifying `sources`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code that gets called by the block named `completion()` in your code snippet is iterating over another collection and is doing so while that array is being modified.  Keep in mind that the `completionHandler` of `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` runs on a background thread, so your code may be performing unsafe concurrent operations on objects when `completionHandler` gets called.

Comment: you are almost correct. In fact there was a concurrency issue. These lines were not connected. Someone was iterating and mutating on a singleton, though it wasn't related to healthkit. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this happens in a block somewhere in a method named

```
[HKAnchoredObjectQuery initWithType:predicate:anchor:limit:completionHandler:]
```

So my guess is that the block in question is the completion handler, and the completion handler gets called asynchronously - while someone else is iterating through the same array and maybe modifying it.

Unfortunately this error doesn't show who is causing the trouble, only who is finding the trouble. I'd set a breakpoint on your own callback, check if it is called from a fast enumeration, and try to figure out who else might be modifying the data. Good luck.